# Cat5e cable: what are each color used for?

Tags: color, cat5e

I have been curious on this for a while since there are some people who use a modified CAT5e cable with a switch to disconnect data sending without actually disconnecting the whole internet connection.

For the above statement: I will explain further: they cut the green wire inside the CAT5e cable, attach a switch and from there they can just simply switch on and off without actually disconnecting.

Can someone explain what colors correspond to what functions in Cat5e?

If so I would be very appreciative. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEMI-DUPLEX:

1. TX+: Simplex (Transmit), positive

2. TX-: Simplex (Transmit), negative

3. RX+: Simplex (Receive), positive

6. RX-: Simplex (Receive), negative

FULL DUPLEX:

1. TX_D1+: Simplex (Transmit), positive
2. TX_D1-: Simplex (Transmit), negative
3. RX_D2+: Simplex (Receive), positive
4. RX_D2-: Simplex (Receive), negative
5. BI_D3+: Duplex channel 1, positive
6. BI_D3-: Duplex channel 1, negative
7. BI_D4+: Duplex channel 2, positive
8. BI_D4-: Duplex channel 2, negative

Comment: interesting, that's quite clear enough with the picture from Denis below... :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the wiring scheme. This table is copied from the Wikipedia page for [TIA/EIA-568-B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568-B):

[alt text http://netstrata.com/images/T568.png](http://netstrata.com/images/T568.png)